# How to access protected variable which is in std object

Tags: php

Hello I have a result in protected variables in std object. When I do `print_r` the result is

```
            libphonenumber\PhoneNumber Object
(
    [countryCode:protected] => 91
    [nationalNumber:protected] => 321476551
    [extension:protected] => 
    [italianLeadingZero:protected] => 
    [rawInput:protected] => 
    [countryCodeSource:protected] => 4
    [preferredDomesticCarrierCode:protected] => 
    [hasNumberOfLeadingZeros:protected] => 
    [numberOfLeadingZeros:protected] => 1
)
```

I want to access the variable country Code. When I do this

```
echo $phoneNumberObject->countryCode;
```

It says

```
Cannot access protected property libphonenumber\PhoneNumber::$countryCode in...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: oh thank you very much. your solution worked

Comment: Please post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use Reflection or other sidesteps of the normal process - protected and private variables in any class cannot be accessed outside of the class.  Normally though any API will provide various methods to access data.

So usually you will find something like `getCountryCode()` in the `PhoneNumber` class.

If there isn't such a method - then this may indicate the variable isn't something you should be accessing and is more likely an internal state rather than a useful value.